# Running iterations in R to create a new variable with specific conditions

Tags: r, iteration, recode

So I have this data and what I would like to do is to create a variable that would reflect the group with the highest status in every given year. Each group can either have the status of:
* 1= Monopoly,
* 2= Dominant,
* 3= Senior,
* 4= Junior or
* 5= Discriminated.
Groups that are either 1 or 2 would automatically get the highest status as each country would only have one group that holds that status in any given year. Some countries, however, have multiple groups belonging to 3 (and 3 is also, sometimes, the highest group status that can be attained in that country for that year) and in that case, I would like the group with the largest size to be coded as the one with the highest status. How may I go about doing this?

**Data**

```
 D1 <- data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
           country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US","US", "US", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"),
           year = c(1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995), 
           group = c("White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino","English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "French", "French", "French", "French", "French"), 
           groupstatus = c("1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "5", "5","5", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4"), 
           groupsize= c(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
```

**Desired Output**

```
D1 <- data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US","US", "US", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
year = c(1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995), 
group = c("White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino", "Latino","English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "French", "French", "French", "French", "French"),            
groupstatus = c("1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "5", "5","5", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4"), 
groupsize= c(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 
highest= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `data.table`.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(D1)`).  Grouped by 'country' and 'year', we create a binary column 'highest' based on the presence of values 1 and 2 in the 'groupstatus'  (It could be also done in one step, but for easier understanding I am splitting it up).

In the next step, grouped by the same columns, we check whether all the elements in the 'groupstatus' is 3 (`all(groupstatus==3)`).  If that is the case, we get the logical index of the maximum 'groupsize' (`groupsize==max(groupsize)`) or `else` (i.e if some values in 'groupstatus' are not 3), we look for the groups with 'highest' values are all '0' or 'FALSE' (`!any(highest)`) and 'groupstatus' is 3 (`groupstatus==3`).  The resulting logical vector can be changed to 'numeric' row index by `.I`.  We extract the row index column (`$V1`) and use that to change the values in 'highest' to 1.

```
 setDT(D1)[, highest := +(groupstatus %in% 1:2) , .(country, year)]
 indx <- D1[, .I[if(all(groupstatus==3)) groupsize==max(groupsize) 
     else !any(highest)& groupstatus==3], .(country, year)]$V1
 D1[indx, highest := 1L]
```

Comment: Hello Akrun, I have been double checking my data and for some reason this code is converting ALL of the groupstatus==3 to highest instead of the one's that are the largest size in a given year, given that there are no 1s or 2s that year. Would you happen to know why this is?

Comment: @rbeginner One way we could check is by having an example that mimics it.  Can you update with a new example that will take care of it.

Comment: the example theoretically would have mimicked the problem but when running it in the complete dataset, there seems to be issues. i am not exactly how sure how to do this but it is imperative that there is only one group per country-year in the end. i will post the dput() of a subset of my data. maybe this will help.